# Нормализация данных в нейронных сетях

Tags: нейронные-сети

Нормализация входных данных происходит **до** умножения данных на веса или **после** умножения  данных на веса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то в нейронной сети нужно использовать уже нормализованные данные. Есть исключения, например в некоторых типах сетей где используется линейная функция активации, там нормализация не требуется.

Comment: Вы всё правильно поняли! Спасибо за ответ!